# Incidence from two seperate data sets

Tags: r

I am very new to R and trying to figure out how to put two datasets together.
I have one table (imported from excel) with information about the people who have certain disease - information about birth year and gestational age e.g. person number 1 = 1990 in one column and 40 in the second.
In another set I have information on how many people with that gestational age were born that year. So for 1990, 1991 etc I have information for number of people born after 37 weeks, 38 weeks etc.

I want to calculate incidence of the disease based on gestational age. So for example if there are 8 people born 1990 after 40 weeks with the disease and 5000 people born in total 1990 after 40 weeks gestation then the incidence is 8/5000...

Any ideas or just links to answers on how to put the datasets together and the code for calculating stuff like or similar to this?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>%
  group_by(disease, gestation) %>%
  tally() %>%
  left_join(., dat2, by = "gestation") %>%
  mutate(occurrence = n/count)
# # A tibble: 510 x 6
# # Groups:   disease [10]
#    disease gestation     n  year count occurrence
#    <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
#  1 A              35    12  1965   447     0.0268
#  2 A              35    12  1969   655     0.0183
#  3 A              35    12  1981   930     0.0129
#  4 A              35    12  1983   146     0.0822
#  5 A              35    12  1984   348     0.0345
#  6 A              35    12  1985   553     0.0217
#  7 A              35    12  1987   655     0.0183
#  8 A              35    12  1988   462     0.0260
#  9 A              35    12  1993    11     1.09  
# 10 A              35    12  1995   434     0.0276
# # ... with 500 more rows
```

---

Data

```r
set.seed(42) # R-4
n <- 1000
dat1 <- data.frame(
  people = sample(1000, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  born = sample(1960:2010, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  disease = sample(LETTERS[1:10], size=n, replace=TRUE),
  gestation = sample(35:40, size=n, replace=TRUE)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(
  year = 1960:2010,
  gestation = sample(35:40, size=51, replace=TRUE),
  count = sample(1:1000, size=51, replace=TRUE)
)

head(dat1)
#   people born disease gestation
# 1    561 2006       C        36
# 2    997 1973       I        37
# 3    321 1976       J        38
# 4    153 1996       J        38
# 5     74 2008       A        39
# 6    228 1976       B        40
head(dat2)
#   year gestation count
# 1 1960        39   385
# 2 1961        38   104
# 3 1962        40   683
# 4 1963        40   770
# 5 1964        36   111
# 6 1965        35   447
```